Draw tcolorbox boxed title over interior
I found this boxed title style on page 186 of the tcolorbox manual (v6.4.0, 2024-09-27):

I want the title box to overlay the content. But when the text is shifted up, we see that the text overlays the title box:

How can I make the titlebox overlay the interior?
For context:
I am using this box's style in a tcbraster environment. Inside of that environment I use \tcbincludepdf to include multi-page PDFs.
So the box content is the PDF pages.
And I want the title to overlay the box content.
Here is the code for the first box:
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz, varwidth}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
    enhanced, 
    before skip=2mm,
    after skip=2mm, 
    colback=black!5,
    colframe=black!50,
    boxrule=0.2mm, 
    attach boxed title to top left={
        xshift=1cm, yshift*=1mm-\tcboxedtitleheight
    }, 
    varwidth boxed title*=-3cm, 
    boxed title style={
        frame code={
            \path[fill=tcbcolback!30!black] ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1mm]frame.north west) arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1mm] ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=1mm]frame.north east) arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=1mm]; 
            \path[left color=tcbcolback!60!black,right color=tcbcolback!60!black, middle color=tcbcolback!80!black] ([xshift=-2mm]frame.north west)-- ([xshift=2mm]frame.north east) [rounded corners=1mm]-- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east)-- (frame.south east)-- (frame.south west)-- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west) [sharp corners]-- cycle; 
        },
        interior engine=empty, 
    }, 
    fonttitle=\bfseries, 
    title={#2}, 
    #1
}

\begin{mybox}[colbacktitle=green]{My title} \lipsum[2] \end{mybox}

\end{document}

The second box is the same, but with option top=-3mm.
Just as a test I tried to recreate the title box inside overlay, but that seems to be drawn under the interior as well.
overlay={
        \node[fill=none, draw=none, opacity=0, yshift=-0.5\baselineskip+\pgflinewidth] (boxed-title) at (frame.north) {\tcbtitle};
        \path[fill=blue!30!black] 
            ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1mm]boxed-title.north west) arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1mm] 
            ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=1mm]boxed-title.north east) arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=1mm]; 
        \path
        [left color=blue!60,right color=blue!60, middle color=blue!80] 
        ([xshift=-2mm]boxed-title.north west)-- ([xshift=2mm]boxed-title.north east) [rounded corners=1mm]-- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]boxed-title.north east)-- (boxed-title.south east)-- (boxed-title.south west)-- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]boxed-title.north west) [sharp corners]-- cycle; 
        \node at (boxed-title) {\tcbtitle};
    },

I don't really know what else to try.
I would appreciate any solution for this, even a hacky one.

you could make the image the background of the box? there are examples of that in the manual. then you just need to add invisible content of the same size. (not saying this is the best solution and clearly not great, but as a last resort ....)

@cfr yeah, that would definitely work for a single image, but I'm including multiple multi-page PDFs with \tcbincludepdf, and I'm not sure how that could be put in the box background without manually including every single page. I'll edit the post to make it clearer.

you'd just need a function to iterate over the pages, wouldn't you? I don't know if there's an engine-independent way to get that number, but you could always use branching logic for that bit if there isn't. but perhaps I'm just misunderstanding the problem?

In the drawing scheme finish (p.167) activated after text.
Remark the fist node {my title} is not visible. I create a \makemytitle command
To manage the color I use \NewTcolorbox
Code
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{tikz, varwidth}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makemytitle}{ m }
    {
        \node[anchor=west,font=\bfseries] (A) at ([yshift=-2mm,xshift=5mm]frame.north west){#1};
    }
% \newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
\NewTColorBox{mybox}{ O{red} m !O{} }
    {
    enhanced, 
    before skip=2mm,
    after skip=2mm, 
    colback=black!5,
    colframe=black!50,
    boxrule=0.2mm, 
    attach boxed title to top left={
        xshift=1cm, yshift*=1mm-\tcboxedtitleheight
    }, 
    % varwidth boxed title*=-3cm, 
    % boxed title style={
    %     frame code={
    %         \path[fill=tcbcolback!30!black] ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1mm]frame.north west) arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1mm] ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=1mm]frame.north east) arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=1mm]; 
    %         \path[left color=tcbcolback!60!black,right color=tcbcolback!60!black, middle color=tcbcolback!80!black] ([xshift=-2mm]frame.north west)-- ([xshift=2mm]frame.north east) [rounded corners=1mm]-- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east)-- (frame.south east)-- (frame.south west)-- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west) [sharp corners]-- cycle; 
    %     },
    %     interior engine=empty, 
    % }, 
    % fonttitle=\bfseries, 
    % title={#2},
    finish={
        % \begin{tcbclipframe}
            \makemytitle    {#2}%<-- not visible
        % \node[font=\bfseries] at(A) {#2};
            \path[fill=#1!30!black]
            (A.north west)+(-1mm,-1mm)
            arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1mm]
            ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=1mm]A.north east)
            arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=1mm];
            \path[left color=#1!60!black,right color=#1!60!black,
            middle color=#1!80!black]
            ([xshift=-2mm]A.north west) -- ([xshift=2mm]A.north east)
            [rounded corners=1mm]-- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]A.north east)
            -- (A.south east) -- (A.south west)
            -- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]A.north west)
            [sharp corners]-- cycle;
            \makemytitle    {#2}
            % \node[font=\bfseries] at(A) {#2};
        % \end{tcbclipframe}
        },
        #3
}

\begin{mybox}[green]{My title} 
    \lipsum[2] 
\end{mybox}


\end{document}



Thanks, I'll play around with this and see if I can adapt it to my use case. Since I'm using the box style in tcbraster to include many multi-page PDFs, manually placing the tikzmark is not really an option for me.

with finish, I edited my answer
